# Porting Newlib with current autotools

Tags: operating-system, kernel, autotools

I'm trying to build a toolchain for my hobby kernel, but I'm running into problems when building Newlib. Whenever I try to run `autoreconf` in my kernels directory under newlib/libc/sys/ I get an error:

```
configure.in:5: error: support for Cygnus-style trees has been removed
```

Here is the content of configure.in (basically, taken from the below tutorial):

```
AC_PREREQ(2.59)
AC_INIT([newlib], [NEWLIB_VERSION])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([crt0.S])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR(../../../..)
NEWLIB_CONFIGURE(../../..)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and the source for Makefile.am (again mostly from tutorial):

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = cygnus
INCLUDES = $(NEWLIB_CFLAGS) $(CROSS_CFLAGS) $(TARGET_CFLAGS)
AM_CCASFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)

noinst_LIBRARIES = lib.a

if MAY_SUPPLY_SYSCALLS
    extra_objs = $(lpfx)syscalls.o
else
    extra_objs =
endif

lib_a_SOURCES =
lib_a_LIBADD = $(extra_objs)
EXTRA_lib_a_SOURCES = syscalls.c crt0.S
lib_a_DEPENDENCIES = $(extra_objs)
lib_a_CCASFLAGS = $(AM_CCASFLAGS)
lib_a_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)

if MAY_SUPPLY_SYSCALLS
    all: crt0.o
endif

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I ../../..
CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES = $(newlib_basedir)/configure.host
```

Yes, I have tried removing the `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS=cygnus`.

I've Googled around and been trying to understand this, and as far as I can tell, it is because of the version of autotools I'm using. According to the tutorial I used originally ([OSDev - OS Specific Toolchain](http://wiki.osdev.org/OS_Specific_Toolchain)), I need an older version. My problem is that I'm using Kubuntu, which uses the apt package manager, and that version is not available to fall back to even temporarily. There has to be some fix for this. Either Newlib is outdated (this release is from December of 2013...) or the developers are crazy for depending on an outdated autotools version.

The only other thing I can think is that this is a message from the newlib configuration scheme itself in which case I have no idea how to modify my configure.in and Makefile.am to align with the new newlib configure format. That tutorial is the only one I've found that didn't use libgloss (which I'd prefer not to do) so far and the documentation of adding a new target is rather lacking in the documentation for newlib (or I missed something).

Here is some version information:

- System: Kubuntu 14.04
- Automake: 1.14.1
- Autoconf: 2.69
- Newlib: 2.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm afraid using automake 1.12 or earlier is your only choice. Ubuntu has an `Automake1.11` separate package to help you there, if I'm not mistaken, since the compatibility between 1.12 and 1.14 is generally good, but before that it was spotty.

Comment: Oh, well. I only checked with `apt-cache showpkg automake` and looked under versions. I didn't realize it was under a completely separate package. I uninstalled automake and then installed automake1.11 and it works now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer for people struggling with the tutorial described [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib).

I am in the same situation you are (or were), I am building a kernel from scratch and I wanted to port newlib to my toolchain. Unfortunately I think the tutorial has become out of date because I followed the instructions EXACTLY, even installing the correct software with the proper versions (including the correct newlib version). The accepted solution above didn't work for me but I found another solution that might work for others:

### Step 1 - get the correct software

- Acquire Automake (v1.12) and Autoconf (v2.65) from here:

  - http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.12.tar.gz
  - http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.65.tar.gz

### Step 2 - build process

Untar both of the archives:

```
tar xf automake-1.12.tar.gz
tar xf autoconf-2.65.tar.gz
```

Create a destination folder:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Create a build folder:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Configure automake first:

```
../automake-1.12/configure --prefix="~/bin"
```

Make and install

```
make && make install
```

Now lets configure autoconf

```
../autoconf-2.65/configure --prefix=~/bin
```

Then make and install:

```
make && make install
```

You should now have the proper binaries in `~/bin`!

### Step 3 - update PATH

To add these binaries to your path temporarily (recommended):

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Once you update your path, rerun `autoconf` and `autoreconf` and it should complete.